# gnome-disk-utility does not open on current screen

Tags: 18.04, gnome-disk-utility

With Ubuntu 14.04, whenever I clicked with my mouse on "disks", the utility opened up on the current screen. Now that I have Ubuntu 18.04 it opens up on a hidden screen I have to drag from the right border of my screen. The same for "Cheese". I assume this is the normal behaviour but wondered if there was a means to open it up on main screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Run in terminal:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows true
   ```

   or
3. Open  dconf Editor go to org > gnome > mutter click on center-new-windows and change it to true.

   or
4. Check CompizConfig Settings Manager > Window Management > Place Windows

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I could install dconf-editor and open org > gnome > mutter so as to click on center-new-windows changing it to true. Nevertheless it did change nothing to my hidden screen behaviour, even after powering off and restarting.

Comment: Se edit, maybe Compiz works.

Comment: thank you so much and sorry for all the burden. For some unknown reason gnome-disk-utility and cheese installed themselves on nonexistant secondary monitor. The simplest thing I had to do was to reset display to Single Monitor, Built-in-Display. There must be a bug somewhere.